# Export grid with images - YII2 gridview widget

Tags: yii2

I am exporting the data in Yii2 using ExportMenu widget of Kartik.

When I export the xls, I can see the rows but without images, the images are shown via `<img>` tag and the images are in one of the upload directories.

[image]

**This is how my table looks like:**

[image]

**That's how The export code is written:**

```
   echo \kartik\export\ExportMenu::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' =>$exportColumns
    ]);
```

Comment: If it can still help you I have a solution

Comment: share the solution please @FrancescoSimeoli

Answer (score 2):

The widget does not export images directly, but exposes the instance of `Spreadsheet`. Through this object you can access the sheet and attach the images.

So you can achieve this in various ways; the simplest and cleanest is to use the `onRenderDataCell` parameter, in the widget configuration array. This accepts an anonymous function that receives the following parameters:

```
function(PhpOffice\PHP\Spreadsheet\Cell $cell, $content, $model, $key, $index, kartik\export\Export\Menu $widget) {   }
```

and is invoked for each cell added into the XLS.

For each one, check if it is an image: with a regular expression, the img tag, the existence of the file, the extension, the mime-type, etc.

Using the `$cell` object, you can add the images to specific cells.
Below is a complete example:

```
<?php

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;


use kartik\export\ExportMenu;
use kartik\grid\GridView;
use yii\data\ArrayDataProvider;
use yii\helpers\Html;

// example data
$dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
    'allModels' => [
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => "Mario",
            'image' => 'img/mario.jpeg',
        ],
        [
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => "Luigi",
            'image' => 'img/luigi.jpg',
        ],
    ]
]);

// grid columns
$gridColumns = [
    'id',
    'name',
    [
        'attribute' => 'image',
        'content' => function($model) {
            return Html::img($model['image']);
        },
        'value' => function($model) {
            return $model['image'];
        },
        'format' => 'raw'
    ]
];

// export menu
echo ExportMenu::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => $gridColumns,
        'onRenderDataCell' => function(PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Cell $cell, $content, $model, $key, $index, kartik\export\ExportMenu $widget) {
            $column = $cell->getColumn();
            $columnIndex = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate::columnIndexFromString($column) - 1;
            $value = array_values($model)[$columnIndex];
            if(file_exists($value)) {   // change the condition as you prefer
                /* @var PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet $worksheet */
                $firstRow = 2;  // skip header row
                $imageName = "Image name";      // Add a name
                $imageDescription = "Image description";    // Add a description
                $padding = 5;
                $imageWidth = 60;   // Image width
                $imageHeight = 60;  // Image height
                $cellID = $column . ($index + $firstRow);   // Get cell identifier
                $worksheet = $cell->getWorksheet();
                $worksheet->getRowDimension($index + $firstRow)->setRowHeight($imageHeight + ($padding * 2));
                //$worksheet->getColumnDimension($column)->setAutoSize(false);
                //$worksheet->getColumnDimension($column)->setWidth($imageWidth + ($padding * 2));
                $drawing = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing();
                $drawing->setName($imageName);
                $drawing->setDescription($imageDescription);
                $drawing->setPath($value); // put your path and image here
                $drawing->setCoordinates($cellID);
                //$drawing->setOffsetX(200);
                $drawing->setWidth($imageWidth);
                $drawing->setHeight($imageHeight);
                //$drawing->setWidthAndHeight($imageWidth, $imageHeight);
                $drawing->setWorksheet($worksheet);

            }
        },
        'dropdownOptions' => [
            'label' => 'Export All',
            'class' => 'btn btn-secondary'
        ]
    ]) . "<hr>\n";

// grid view
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => $gridColumns,
]);
```

Alternatively you can extend the `ExportMenu` class and use a similar technique (with the `Spreadsheet` object) and guarantee native support for exporting images (you will need to maintain the class in case of updates).

**RESULT**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, for `PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;` are you using the core one from git and placed it in vendor folder?

Comment: The library is in the vendor folder, but if you are using `composer`, it is automatically imported as a dependency of `kartik-v/yii2-export`

Comment: i am using older version of yii2 so i have not been able to have the latest version of yii2-export

Comment: Older versions of `kartik-v/yii2-export` requires `phpoffice/phpexcel` instead of `PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet`. So, you have several options: (1) update the framework, (2) modify only the dependencies in the require block of the `composer.json` file to import `PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet` library (you have to check all dependencies), (3) use the old `PHPExcel` library adopting a solution similar to the one shown, (4) import `PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet` and add the images after generating the file.